# Uploading a .py file through a form in django, and importing the functions defined in it in view.py

Tags: python, django

I want to upload a .py file that contains some defined functions through form input method. Then in **view.py** i want to use that functions which are defined in this uploaded python file. What would be the method of importing those funtions.

i am able to upload the file, but dont know how to import the functions.

Comment: add code of how you are calling the function from the other file

Comment: save code in file ie. `code.py` and use `import code`. Or you can try  `eval(text_with_code)` or `exec(text_with_code)`